# .map() nested array not working JavaScript

Tags: javascript, json

I am having issues with using the .map function in JavaScript to extract a nested array from an api response.

here is the JSON:

```
[
    {
        "id": 3787,
        "title": "Dummy title!",
        "start_time": "2020-04-25T16:54:00.000Z",
        "created_at": "2020-04-25T17:22:13.315Z",
        "updated_at": "2020-04-25T17:32:15.364Z",
        "incident_updates": [
            {
                "id": 9905,
                "body": "Dummy Paragraph test!",
```

Here is the code that I put together my script.js file:

```
fetch(url)
.then((response) => {
  if (!response.ok) {
    throw Error("ERROR");
  }
  return response.json();
})
.then((data) => {
  console.log(data);
  const html = data
    .map((item) => {
      console.log(item.incident_updates[0]);
      return `<div class="card card-space">
      <div class="card-body">
      <h5 class="card-title">${item.title}</h5>
      <h6 class="card-subtitle mb-2 text-muted">${item.start_time}</h6>
      <p class="card-text">${item.incident_updates.body}</p> // issues with this
      </div>
      </div>`;
    })
    .join("");
```

for whatever reason everything else is working fine like item.title & item.start_time however **item.incident_updates.body** doesn't work at all and in my HTML file it says "Undefined".

How am I able to get render the data from incident_updates.body?

Thanks guys!

Comment: `item.incident_updates` is an array. Therefor you cannot not access `item.incident_updates.body`. You need something like `item.incident_updates[0].body`

Comment: `item.incident_updates` is an array. You should use `.map()` again inside the existing map and perform the same trick.

Comment: you should clarify your question. How do you want to decide which item of `item.incident_updates` should be taken? How does `data` look like after resolving `response.json()`?

Answer (score 0):

incident_updates is an array, so you will need an index first to get the right element. Try something like this where *i* is the index of the element you're after:

```
var i = 0;
item.incident_updates[i].body
```

Comment: this is correct, but imho the OP's question is not clarified enough. There may be cases where he wants to display the body of another item inside that array

Comment: still learning JS but all I need to try and get is the Incident_updates.body. Don't know how to include it inside .map

Comment: also item.incident_updates[0].body doesn't work. It gives me an undefined error

Comment: @Johan it gives me an array

Comment: That's wierd, could you make a jsfiddle without the request that reproduces the problem? And link it here, it feels like some information is missing

Answer (score 0):

Since item.incident_updates is an array you can use map for that

```
const html = data
.map((item) => {
  console.log(item.incident_updates[0]);
  return `<div class="card card-space">
  <div class="card-body">
  <h5 class="card-title">${item.title}</h5>
  <h6 class="card-subtitle mb-2 text-muted">${item.start_time}</h6>
  {item.incident_updates.map((data)={return(<p class="card-text">${data.body}</p>)})}
  </div>
  </div>`;
})
```

Comment: im using VSCode and the test is dimmed out in colour and it has red error lines and when I hover over it it says "remove unreachable code"